# PLSQL program should run on any day between 1 and 5 of every month and between 25 and last day month

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PLSQL program with three cursors.  This program should run as a job.

The job should run on any day between 1st and 5th of every month. And also between 25th and last day of every month.   How to write a logic to run this program?

Answer (score 3):

I would set a database job to run every day and then make a simple if clause at the start of the program to check if it's valid day to run the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the DBMS_SCHEDULER routines. 
The new version (v3) of Oracle's SQL Developer has a nice GUI for setting up schedules